# ngb-alert only works with type="success" or without type

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I have this following code which works.

```
<ngb-alert *ngIf="alertError" class="fade animate-show animate-hide"  (close)="alertError = false"><strong>{{ message }}</strong></ngb-alert>
<ngb-alert *ngIf="alertSuccess" class="animate-show animate-hide" type="success" (close)="alertSuccess = false"><strong>{{ message }}</strong></ngb-alert>
```

But if I change to the following it doesn't

```
<ngb-alert *ngIf="alertError" class="fade animate-show animate-hide" type="danger" (close)="alertError = false"><strong>{{ message }}</strong></ngb-alert>
<ngb-alert *ngIf="alertSuccess" class="animate-show animate-hide" type="primary" (close)="alertSuccess = false"><strong>{{ message }}</strong></ngb-alert>
```

My package.json is like this.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "~1.0.0-alpha.30",
    "angular-loader": "^1.6.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "primeng": "^4.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "screenshot-desktop": "^1.1.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.53",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.19",
    "codelyzer": "^3.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.7.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.1.1",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "tslint": "^5.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
```

So, can some expert please tell me what's wrong here? Why type primary or danger won't work.

Answer (score 6):

I ran across a similar issue. My problem was that Angular thought I was passing it a variable from which to read the type from. Obviously there was no variable titled `primary` so it failed. changing things to `[type]="'primary'"` solved the issue altogether.

```html
<ngb-alert *ngIf="alertSuccess" class="animate-show animate-hide" [type]="'primary'" (close)="alertSuccess = false"><strong>{{ message }}</strong></ngb-alert>
```

Comment: Holy crap, this was driving me insane! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just **not allowed to use the `fade` class** here.

```
class="fade animate-show animate-hide"
```

If I run your code, it only shows me the success.
But if I remove the `fade` class, it shows both messages.

## EDIT

I compared your list of dependencies to mine.

Have you tried updating your libs? 
You can run this from the command line:

```
npm update -D && npm update -S
```

Dependencies that you have, that I don't :

```
"angular-loader": "^1.6.5",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"primeng": "^4.1.3",
"screenshot-desktop": "^1.1.0",
"underscore": "^1.8.3"
```

I am especially wondering about that first one [`angular-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-loader).
Do you know what it's for ? According to its documentation it's a Angular**JS** dependency.

Comment: I tried but still didn't work for me. I guess something else is causing this.

Comment: I will try to compare the dependency list that you provided, with mine

Comment: updated my answer with a list of dependency differences. I hope that can help you to track down the issue.